# Best way around this registration/validation hack

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, windows, visual-studio

I wrote a registration key script that works great when the applcation is on a computer that is connected to the internet. However, I would like to get the script to work when the application is on a computer that remains offline. I was hoping you guys could give me a couple of ideas of how to get this to work.

How the script works.

1. The user installs the application
2. On the opening screen the user clicks a "FingerPrint" button to generate a code that is unique to his computer (Combination of OS and Hardware information)
3. User submits the fingerprint
4. I have an application on my end where I take his fingerprint, add an expiration date, and it outputs a keyfile that is unique to his computer that will render the application useless until the keyfile is renewed.
5. To check expiration date, the application does a server check everytime the applcation is loaded.

So the problem I am facing is that when the computer is offline, it will use the system time to check for the expiration date. Well so far nothing is perventing people from keeping their computers offline and just rolling back the system clock.

Other then forcing the user to be online for the loading of the application, I can't seem to think of a reasonable system check - and other then the server check, there is no need for this application to be online. I know tricky, and I am stumped.

Any help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, users will always find a way to break your offline licensing mechanism and often will. So consider it before putting any effort in it.

You will need to make change to your licensing mechanism. This is a lot more difficult considering that there may be users already using your application on older mechanism. You might have to either retain both licensing mechanisms or provide an update to existing users if you want to stick only to new one.

For implementing an offline licensing scheme, you can make use of [LicenseManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.licensemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. Please note that this can never be as effective as your current method. Here is simple way I can think of:

1. Generate an ID when the user installs or first loads the application.
2. Encrypt it along date installed with algorithm of your choice. Save it in registry or an XML file.
3. Each time user opens the application, encrypt and save the last used date.
4. If at any point of time, current date is less than last used date, do not update last used date. Instead, tell users to update the current date (ensure to take care of timezones and daylight saving).

If your users are using your application rarely, they can still play around with it.

Comment: I finally finished it and I think it's looking pretty good Steps: 1. The program loads 2. User must be connected to the internet to create a fingerprint that is unique to the computer and time 4. User passes the code to me which then I generate a seperate code to unlock the computer until an expiration date 5. The program updates the time everytime the application loads and exits to make sure time is moving forward 6. Application also connects to the internet when it finds it to update time 7. Anytime the time doesnt sync the computer locks until the time is verified by the net

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, you cannot trust the client to provide accurate time data.  Without access to a trusted time source, you cannot reliably prevent the attack you describe using an expiration date alone.

You could mandate use of a trusted time source (some USB PRNG dongle with an internal RTC used as the seed, for example) to validate the system clock, and then block the application running.  However, such dongles typically cost upwards of $60 per unit for low volumes.

A simple countermeasure would be to record the *amount* of time the application has been open, then terminate if the application has been open for too long without checking in.  I.E.: if your expected check-in frequency is 3 months, and the computer says it is 3 days since you last checked in, but the application has been opened for 45 days, you can be assured the clock is incorrect.

Even still, your code is running on the client's untrusted computer, and can be subverted.  Any measure of DRM is still just obfuscation.